# D3 histogram, can't get bars within axis

Tags: d3.js, histogram

I'm trying to let the user plot a histogram from different sets of data. The user will be able to input how many bars should be shown.

My problem is one of the bars end up outside of my x-axis.

Here is a [JSFiddle with the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/t4ho787f/9/)

What am I missing?

I think the problem might be around this code:

```
var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 1)
        .attr("width", width/data.length)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What values should be on the X axis and what values should be on the Y axis?

Comment: On the x axis I show a linear scale with the range for all the values in the dataset, on the y axis I show the frequency of the data within that range occuring. The problem is that the bars doesn't align with the x axis correctly and the last bar ends up outside the axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

This should do the job: https://jsfiddle.net/t4ho787f/11/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var values = [79.86, 59.57, 39.64, 49.08, 21.34, 17.05, 30.8, 3.63, 4.71, 9.88, 67.55, 71.01, 60.3, 50.95, 60.37, 48.14, 51.9, 16.91, 3.52, 67.98];

    var rawData2 = [17000, 30000, 25000, 22000, 25000, 20000, 25000, 35000, 20000, 20000, 18000, 15000];

    var userTicks = 20;

console.log("Histogram plot goes here")

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 60};
    var width = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas-0")[0].clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas-0")[0].clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(values), d3.max(values)])
    .range([0, width]);

    var data = d3.layout.histogram()
        .bins(x.ticks(userTicks))
        (values);        

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(userTicks);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");


    var svg = d3.select(".canvas-0").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 1)
//        .attr("width", function (d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });

    bar.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", x(data[0].dx) / 2)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.y; });

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);


});
```

Comment: No sorry, the bins (nr of bars) is a number which the user will specify. The problem with my JSFiddle is just that the bars doesn't fit with the x axis.

Comment: See my updated answer above. Try the code. Is this what you're looking for? You can change the userTicks variable to whatever the user defines...

Comment: Not exactly as I need it but you found the place where the bug was. It was in the x scales .domain() where i had the wrong range. With some tweaks I managed to get it as I wanted.